# DateTime.ParseExact to UTC value

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I retrieve a date and time from my web api and set it as so :

```
tmp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAndTimeFromApi, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

I need to convert this DateTime to a UTC DateTime. When I add .ToUniversalTime() it does not convert from local to UTC. My current timezone is UTC + 2.
So I want to get from 11am to 9am after the conversion.

How can I do this if I want to keep the "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a couple of DateTimeStyles (in the System.Globalization namespace) flags as the 4th parameter.

By default the resulting DateTime will have an `Unsepcified` DateTimeKind therefore adjustments between local and UTC will fail. - `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` will  make sure that DateTimeKind.Local is set.

The `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` flag will also perform the conversion between DateTimeKind.Local and DateTimeKind.UTC

```
var tmp = DateTime.ParseExact("28/07/2022 10:51:25", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Comment: `ParseExact` is surprisingly powerful. Nice!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand better now why the conversion was not working, my DateTime is not set as Local Time so it can't convert to UTC , but the conversion is still not taking place after adding the "DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal" as 4th parameter.
I aslo tried just the ""DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal" and then do a ".ToUniversalTime()" but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you be more specific about _"is still not taking place"_ and _"it doesn't seem to work either"_

Comment: Yes, the date is still the same : "DateTime.ParseExact("28/07/2022 10:51:25", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null)" returns the same value as "DateTime.ParseExact("28/07/2022 10:51:25", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)" They both return 28/07/2022 10:51:25

Comment: Weird, it works fine here at UTC+1. How are you testing/running the code? Does that machine think it's in a UTC+2 timezone?

Comment: Yes the machine executing my code is in UTC+2 timezone. But my goal is to come back to UTC.
My goal :  
(UTC+2) 28/07/2022 10:51:25  =>  (UTC) 28/07/2022 08:51:25

Comment: If I run this at UTC+1 I get `28/07/2022 09:51:25` and it adjusts correctly, must be something else going on!

Comment: What do you get with `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)`?

Comment: I get TimeZone = 00:00:00

Comment: Then, for whatever reason, your code thinks the local timezone is currently equivalent to UTC. That is why you're not seeing a change. Time to check a few assumptions.

Comment: Ok, i have to check what's going on.
Thank you for your time and awnsers !